# ¿Cómo implementar la suma y la diferencia de nodos consecutivos de una lista?

Tags: java

De que manera puedo implementar los métodos que me calculen la suma y la diferencia de el número en un nodo dado de la lista y el número del siguiente.

Aqui les dejo lo que tengo de momento

```
package aplicacionlista;

public class Lista {
    private Nodo primero,ultimo;
    Lista(){
        primero = null;
    }

    public Nodo getPrimero() {
        return primero;
    }


    public void setPrimero(Nodo n) {
        primero = n;
    }
    public Nodo getUltimo() {
        return ultimo;
    }

    public void setUltimo(Nodo n) {
        ultimo = n;
    }
    public void insertarFinal(Nodo n){
        if(primero == null){
            primero = n;ultimo = n;
        }
        else{
            ultimo.setSig(n);
            ultimo = n;
        }
    }
    public void insertarPrincipio(Nodo n){
        if(primero == null){
            primero = n;ultimo = n;
        }
        else{
            n.setSig(primero);
            primero = n;
        }
    }
    public boolean eliminar(Object dato){
        Nodo actual,anterior;
        if(primero == null){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            actual = primero;
            anterior  = null;
            while(true){
                if(actual == null){
                    return false;
                }
                else{
                    if((int)actual.getDato() == (int)dato){
                        if(actual == primero){
                           primero = actual.getSig();
                           actual = null;
                           return true;
                        }
                        else{
                           anterior.setSig(actual.getSig());
                           actual.setSig(null);
                           return true;
                        }

                    }
                    else{
                        anterior = actual;
                        actual = actual.getSig();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public boolean eliminarPares(){
        Nodo actual,anterior;
        if(primero == null){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            actual = primero;
            anterior  = null;
            while(true){
                if(actual == null){
                    return false;
                }
                else{
                    if((int)actual.getDato() % 2 == 0){
                        anterior.setSig(actual.getSig());
                        actual.setSig(null);
                        actual = anterior.getSig();
                    }
                    else{
                        anterior = actual;
                        actual = actual.getSig();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void imprimirLista(){
        Nodo actual;
        if(primero == null){
           System.out.print("La lista esta vacia");
        }
        else{
            actual = primero;
            while(true){
              if(actual == null){
                 break; 
              }
              System.out.println((int)actual.getDato());
              actual = actual.getSig();
            }
        }
    }
}


**aplicaionlista** 


package aplicacionlista;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class AplicacionLista {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Lista l = new Lista();
        int dato;
        while(true){
            System.out.print("Digite dato entero 0-termina:");
            dato = sc.nextInt();
            if(dato == 0){
               break; 
            }
            else{
               Nodo n = new Nodo();
               n.setDato(dato);
               l.insertarFinal(n);
            }
        }
        System.out.print("Ingrese el dato a eliminar:");
        dato = sc.nextInt();
        l.eliminar(dato);
        System.out.println("Imprimir la lista:");
        l.imprimirLista();
    }
}
```

Comment: Que avance tienes hasta el momento? Cual es la duda en especifica?

Comment: ese es el código que llevo hecho,  necesito saber como hago que un  método muestre la suma y la diferencia entre un dato entero encontrado en un nodo y el dato entero del siguiente nodo

Comment: si entendiste amigo?

Answer (score 0):

No sé de que manera quieres buscar el número, pero sería algo como esto.

```js
** lista **


  package aplicacionlista;

public class Lista {
  private Nodo primero, ultimo;
  Lista() {
    primero = null;
  }

  public Nodo getPrimero() {
    return primero;
  }


  public void setPrimero(Nodo n) {
    primero = n;
  }
  public Nodo getUltimo() {
    return ultimo;
  }

  public void setUltimo(Nodo n) {
    ultimo = n;
  }
  public void insertarFinal(Nodo n) {
    if (primero == null) {
      primero = n;
      ultimo = n;
    } else {
      ultimo.setSig(n);
      ultimo = n;
    }
  }
  public void insertarPrincipio(Nodo n) {
    if (primero == null) {
      primero = n;
      ultimo = n;
    } else {
      n.setSig(primero);
      primero = n;
    }
  }
  public boolean eliminar(Object dato) {
    Nodo actual, anterior;
    if (primero == null) {
      return false;
    } else {
      actual = primero;
      anterior = null;
      while (true) {
        if (actual == null) {
          return false;
        } else {
          if ((int) actual.getDato() == (int) dato) {
            if (actual == primero) {
              primero = actual.getSig();
              actual = null;
              return true;
            } else {
              anterior.setSig(actual.getSig());
              actual.setSig(null);
              return true;
            }

          } else {
            anterior = actual;
            actual = actual.getSig();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  public boolean eliminarPares() {
    Nodo actual, anterior;
    if (primero == null) {
      return false;
    } else {
      actual = primero;
      anterior = null;
      while (true) {
        if (actual == null) {
          return false;
        } else {
          if ((int) actual.getDato() % 2 == 0) {
            anterior.setSig(actual.getSig());
            actual.setSig(null);
            actual = anterior.getSig();
          } else {
            anterior = actual;
            actual = actual.getSig();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  public void imprimirLista() {
    Nodo actual;
    if (primero == null) {
      System.out.print("La lista esta vacia");
    } else {
      actual = primero;
      while (true) {
        if (actual == null) {
          break;
        }
        System.out.println((int) actual.getDato());
        actual = actual.getSig();
      }
    }
  }

  public String sumaDif(Object dato) {
    Nodo actual;
    String resultado, suma, dif;
    while (true) {
      if ((int) actual.getDato() == (int) dato) {
        suma = ((int) dato) + ((int) actual.getSig());
        dif = ((int) dato) - ((int) actual.getSig());
        resultado = "Suma: " + suma;
        resultado += "\nDiferencia: " + dif;
        return resultado;
      } else {
        actual = actual.getSig();
      }
    }
    return "No se ha encontrado el dato";
  }
}


**
aplicaionlista **


  package aplicacionlista;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class AplicacionLista {


  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Lista l = new Lista();
    int dato;
    while (true) {
      System.out.print("Digite dato entero 0-termina:");
      dato = sc.nextInt();
      if (dato == 0) {
        break;
      } else {
        Nodo n = new Nodo();
        n.setDato(dato);
        l.insertarFinal(n);
      }
    }
    System.out.print("Ingrese el dato a eliminar:");
    dato = sc.nextInt();
    l.eliminar(dato);
    System.out.println("Imprimir la lista:");
    l.imprimirLista();
    System.out.print("Ingrese el dato a buscar:");
    dato = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println(l.sumaDif(dato));
  }
}
```

Comment: amigo podrias  pasarme el codigoque acabas de hacer ya listo en el codigo que puse de la pregunta?

Comment: Queda mucho más claro si se explica solo el código añadido